# Getting Started with Python on Heroku - Run the app locally step issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am following the "[Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally)" official tutorial. I think the tutorial is basically about setting up a Django Hello World, even though I have not seen the outcome yet.

### These steps worked:

```
   $ git clone https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started.git
   $ heroku create
   $ git push heroku master
```

Output for last command (important part in my opinion):

```
...
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.9)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Django==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading Django-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
remote:        Collecting django-postgrespool==0.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading django-postgrespool-0.3.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz (367kB)
remote:        Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.0.4.tar.gz (4.6MB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==1.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, Django, psycopg2, SQLAlchemy, django-postgrespool, gunicorn, whitenoise
remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2
remote:          Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy
remote:          Running setup.py install for django-postgrespool
remote:        Successfully installed Django-1.8.1 SQLAlchemy-1.0.4 dj-database-url-0.3.0 django-postgrespool-0.3.0 gunicorn-19.3.0 psycopg2-2.6 whitenoise-1.0.6
...
```

Further commands:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
$ heroku open
```

Then a Procfile defined with the following line:

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
```

Then created a virtualenv (tried with both Python 2.7.6. and 3.4.2):

```
$ virtual venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external
```

First time around I had a problem with psycopg2-2.6, which then I believe I successfully installed. Here are all the requirements:
- dj-database-url==0.3.0
- Django==1.8.1
- django-postgrespool==0.3.0
- gunicorn==19.3.0
- psycopg2==2.6
- SQLAlchemy==1.0.4
- whitenoise==1.0.6

### THIS IS WHERE I GOT STUCK:

```
foreman start web
```

Called from the main directory of this project structure:

```
python-getting-started/
├── Procfile
├── Procfile.windows
├── README.md
├── gettingstarted
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── humans.txt
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── db.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── runtime.txt
```

The output of the last command is:

```
23:35:07 web.1  | started with pid 6296
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6296] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6296] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (6296)
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6296] [INFO] Using worker: sync
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6299] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6299
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 22:35:07 +0000] [6299] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
23:35:07 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
23:35:07 web.1  |     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
23:35:07 web.1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_postgrespool/base.py", line 8, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     from psycopg2 import InterfaceError, ProgrammingError, OperationalError
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
23:35:07 web.1  | ImportError: dlopen(/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
23:35:07 web.1  |   Referenced from: /Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
23:35:07 web.1  |   Reason: image not found
23:35:07 web.1  |
23:35:07 web.1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
23:35:07 web.1  |
23:35:07 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
23:35:07 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
23:35:07 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
23:35:07 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
23:35:07 web.1  |     __import__(module)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/gettingstarted/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     application = get_wsgi_application()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
23:35:07 web.1  |     django.setup()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
23:35:07 web.1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
23:35:07 web.1  |     app_config.import_models(all_models)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
23:35:07 web.1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     class Permission(models.Model):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
23:35:07 web.1  |     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
23:35:07 web.1  |     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
23:35:07 web.1  |     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
23:35:07 web.1  |     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
23:35:07 web.1  |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
23:35:07 web.1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend.
23:35:07 web.1  | Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
23:35:07 web.1  |     'base', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
23:35:07 web.1  | Error was: dlopen(/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
23:35:07 web.1  |   Referenced from: /Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
23:35:07 web.1  |   Reason: image not found
23:35:07 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
23:35:07 web.1  |     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
23:35:07 web.1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_postgrespool/base.py", line 8, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     from psycopg2 import InterfaceError, ProgrammingError, OperationalError
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
23:35:07 web.1  | ImportError: dlopen(/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
23:35:07 web.1  |   Referenced from: /Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
23:35:07 web.1  |   Reason: image not found
23:35:07 web.1  |
23:35:07 web.1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
23:35:07 web.1  |
23:35:07 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
23:35:07 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
23:35:07 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
23:35:07 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
23:35:07 web.1  |     __import__(module)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/gettingstarted/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     application = get_wsgi_application()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
23:35:07 web.1  |     django.setup()
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
23:35:07 web.1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
23:35:07 web.1  |     app_config.import_models(all_models)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
23:35:07 web.1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
23:35:07 web.1  |     class Permission(models.Model):
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
23:35:07 web.1  |     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
23:35:07 web.1  |     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
23:35:07 web.1  |     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
23:35:07 web.1  |     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
23:35:07 web.1  |     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
23:35:07 web.1  |   File "/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
23:35:07 web.1  |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
23:35:07 web.1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend.
23:35:07 web.1  | Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
23:35:07 web.1  |     'base', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
23:35:07 web.1  | Error was: dlopen(/Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
23:35:07 web.1  |   Referenced from: /Users/janosbana/developer/playground/Python/heroku/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
23:35:07 web.1  |   Reason: image not found
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 22:35:07 +0000] [6299] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6299)
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6296] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
23:35:07 web.1  | [2015-06-14 23:35:07 +0100] [6296] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
23:35:07 web.1  | exited with code 3
23:35:07 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Please note that I have *postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4* installed on OSX Yosemite.

I think there is some problem with the database configuration, but I am very new to this and find it hard to workout what has happened from the debug log.
I have searched the web trying to find similar cases the output of the last command, however I did not find anything the had the exact same nature as mine.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Please help to figure out what to do about it.

**EDIT:**

An additional step appeared in the Heroku tutorial since this question was asked.

[Run the app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally) step has the following command now:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

This line was added before the step where I got stuck:

```
$ foreman start web
```

Comment: You should post the DATABASES section of your settings.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error, `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend.`, it appears your DATABASE setting is improperly configured.

In your settings file, since you're using postgresql, make sure the database ENGINE is set to `'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`. See the databases [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases) and the database engine [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#engine).

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot up vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation points.